# MySQL - Characters matching

Tags: mysql

How would I get MySQL to be more strict with character matching?

A quick example of what I mean, say I have a table with a single column `name`. In this column, I have two names: 'Jorge' and 'Jorgé" The only difference between these names is the ´ over the e. If I run the query `SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = 'Jorge'`, it will return

```
+--------+
|  name  |
+--------+
| Jorge  |
| Jorgé  |
+--------+
```

and if I run the query `SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = 'Jorgé'`, it returns the same result table. How would I set MySQL to be more strict in that so that it would not return both names?

Thanks ahead.

Quick Edit: I'm using the UTF-8 character encoding

Comment: use HEX or common expressions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make sure that no similar characters (like `e` and `é`) are considered the same, you should use the `utf8_bin` collation on that column.  I assume that you're using `utf8_general_ci` now, which will consider some similar characters to be the same.  `utf8_bin` only matches on the exact same characters.

Answer (score 1):

@G-Nugget is correct, but since you are looking at Spanish stuff you might also be interested in the **utf8_spanish_ci** or **utf8_spanish2_ci**. They correspond to modern and traditional Spanish. "ñ" is considered a separate letter, and in traditional the "ch" and "ll" are also treated as separate letters.

More here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-unicode-sets.html

Comment: Spanish is not the only character set that I'm working with, that was just the first example that came to mind. The `utf8_bin` collation worked for me.